# Install older version of PHP with apt-get

Tags: installation, apt, php

I am trying to install an older version of PHP on my system. I installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 and have tried

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

This does successfully install `php 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8`, however I trying to get `5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1` installed. Can someone point me in the right direction? I have no objection to using something like synaptic, I was able to find the `.deb` files here at [security.ubuntu.com](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/) but it seems to require a huge amount of dependencies.

Is there a way to install the version of php I want with `apt-get` ?

I am open to trying stuff, this is done on a VM and I have taken a snapshot so it can be restored back to its previous state.

Answer (score 1):

In synaptic, search for php, highlight the package and in one of the menus on top, try "Force Version", see if the one you want appears.

Answer (score 1):

No, you wont be able to do that with `apt-get`. The problem is not `apt`, but the fact that only version 5.3.10 is packaged for Ubuntu 12.04.

Also, make sure any pre-compiled software you wish to install matches your kernel version.

Comment: Luís is right, I've just checked and the only version in the official repos is 5.4 so the only solution involves finding a third party repository that packages older versions.